# Yii2 : Invalid Configuration - The directory does not exist

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have moved my existing Yii2 website to a new server but I am unable to access it.
It throws below error

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException The directory
>   does not exist: /home/domain_path/assets

[image]

but the same app is working in the old server without having assets folder at the root.

Is there an issue with `runtime` folder?

Comment: please check your folder permissions. it needs permission to create assets

Comment: Not an issue with permission. It's 777. It is looking for folder in root where it should not look

Comment: asset and runtime folder are required in yii2

Comment: are u using Shared Hosting Environment?

Comment: asset and runtime folders are there with permission. same project working in old server and I had problem that time and fixed but not remember

Comment: can you add the screen grab or the complete error trace for the issue

Comment: do you have defined the `$basepath` property for your assets in your `AppAsset` file and is it writeable? usually, it is `@webroot` if the assets are not loaded from a directory outside `/web`, can you add your assets file, and also login from the control panel and go to `Errors` section to check if it is logging any errors there.

Comment: and the error trace is not a complete trace, you should add the complete text via pastebin for more accurate troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are missing **assets** folder in the `webroot/web` directory.

The value of `$this->basePath` is currently `false` (you can print the value to see it).

So I fixed it by adding **assets** folder to `/web` directory.

Comment: This worked! I have a Yii2 app running inside of Docker, and I was getting this error when loading the /debug page in the browser. I went to the main folder in my IDE, directory `/web`, created a new directory called `assets`, and now I am able to see the debug page just fine.

Answer (score 0):

add directory assets to frontend/web or enother directory, which respond about your front

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).